# gnuplot - data points and interpolation

Tags: gnuplot

I have two columns in my data file:

```
  x  y
  1  5
  1  10
  2  3
  4  5
  4  6
  4  14
```

That is I have a set of results (`y` values) for particular value `x`. I want to produce a graph with gnuplot that shows all the data points shown above and a curve that goes through their average values:

```
  x  y
  1  (5+10)/2
  2  3
  4  (5+6+14)/4
```

This should be fairly simple but I can't find it.

How can I do that?

Comment: This should read `(5+6+14)/3`  which would give `8`. Just be aware of gnuplot's integer division which might create unexpected results ;-). But here you are safe because with `using 1:2`, values are read as floating point number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
plot "datafile" u 1:2 smooth unique
```

does exactly what you want.